# excel - insert single whitespace after every n characters in a string

Tags: excel

Using MS excel - With a string like `0x80808080800180808080808080808080` of 34 chars length - need to convert to to a string like `80 80 80 80 80 01 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80` - that is to strip off the `0x` at the beginning and add single white-space between every two characters in the original string.

The first part is good - `REPLACE(A1,1,2,"")` does it.

need help with the second part.

Update:-

@Jeeped 's answer with UDF based solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39050715/3206440) works - however need a non-UDF solution.

Comment: Unless the length is fixed, you will probably have to write a VBA UDF. Even with a fixed length input, a UDf would be a better choice with [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: input length is fixed - looking for a non-UDF solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this User Defined Function¹.

```
Option Explicit

Function spaceBigHex(str As String, _
                     Optional delim As String = " ")
    Dim i As Long, var As Variant

    'strip off the 0×
    str = Mid(str, 3)

    'insert spaces from right to left        
    For i = Len(str) - 2 To 2 Step -2
        str = Left(str, i) & delim & Mid(str, i + 1)
    Next i

    spaceBigHex = str
End Function
```

[image]

This can also accomplished with a series of native worksheet [REPLACE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181) functions providing the length of the string is static.

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT(A3, LEN(A3)-2),
  31, 0, " "), 29, 0, " "), 27, 0, " "), 25, 0, " "), 23, 0, " "),
  21, 0, " "), 19, 0, " "), 17, 0, " "), 15, 0, " "), 13, 0, " "),
  11, 0, " "), 9, 0, " "), 7, 0, " "), 5, 0, " "), 3, 0, " ")
```

The line feeds are there solely to help you make sense of it. Leave them or remove them; it does not matter one whiff.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Comment: - this solution works - upvoted. However I'm looking for a non-UDF way of doing this.